# Troubleshooting Device Policy Manager library failure on Android 9

Tags: root-access, system, troubleshooting

Running MIUI 11 EU ROM/Redmi Note 7 (x86, x64,arm).

**Logcat:**

```
08-09 02:07:13.089 20371 20371 F linker  : CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/system/bin/dpmd": "/system/lib64/libdpmframework.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit
08-09 02:07:18.098 20372 20372 F linker  : CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/system/bin/dpmd": "/system/lib64/libdpmframework.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit
```

*This repeats few thousands times.*

**Dmesg:**

```
←[32m[25524.718572] ←[33minit←[0m: starting service 'dpmd'...
←[32m[25524.727366] ←[33minit←[0m: Created socket '/dev/socket/dpmd', mode 660, user 0, group 1000
←[32m[25524.728779] ←[33minit←[0m: Created socket '/dev/socket/tcm', mode 660, user 0, group 3003
←[32m[25524.730283] ←[33minit←[0m: Created socket '/dev/socket/dpmwrapper', mode 660, user 0, group 3003
←[32m[25524.750409] ←[33minit←[0m: Service 'dpmd' (pid 21932) exited with status 1
←[32m[25524.750512] ←[33minit←[0m: Sending signal 9 to service 'dpmd' (pid 21932) process group...
←[32m[25524.750803] ←[33mlibprocessgroup←[0m: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 0 pid 21932 in 0ms
```

*(^this is very odd, I've actually disabled DPN autostart in /etc/init/dpm.rc but it still executes and I cant find any more entries for dpm service **anywhere**)*

**Props**

```
←[0mlavender:/etc/init # getprop | grep dpm
[init.svc.dpmQmiMgr]: [running]
[init.svc.dpmd]: [restarting]
[persist.dpm.feature]: [1]
[ro.boottime.dpmQmiMgr]: [10482924682]
[ro.boottime.dpmd]: [10648556660]
```

I tried to google and there are plenty of results for the specific error however they are all related to the program build/compilation against specific platform and for these cases solution is fairly straightforward. In my case, though, I'm not compiling anything, I have no idea why this happens on stock. It looks like some application or service is built against different arch and it tries to bind that lib of specific arch but fails? *But how can I find what app/system app exactly does it?* As you can see, **logcat** and **dmesg** don't have much info.